# C# Invoke only for write access?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

Do I only need to use Invoke, if the access is a write access? Is it safe to get the property of a GUI object without invoke?

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => mbrVerticalProgressBar1.Value++));

if (TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported)
{
   TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressValue(
       mbrVerticalProgressBar1.Value,
       mbrListOfURLsCount);
}
}).Start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN Library makes no bones about it, it declares *every* method and property of the Control class thread-unsafe except InvokeRequired, BeginInvoke, Invoke and CreateGraphics.

That's not entirely accurate, there certainly are a few properties that are accidentally thread-safe because they use a backing variable.  You'd have to know the actual implementation of the property getter and take a gamble on it not going to chance in the future.

And yes, ProgressBar.Value uses such a backing variable, the private *value* field.  You can tell from the Reference Source or a decompiler.  However, that's only for the getter, the setter is most certainly not.  Because it needs to actually get the visible appearance of the control to change.

Btw, *always* favor BeginInvoke over Invoke.  Invoke has pretty unpleasant characteristics, it is very apt to cause deadlock and it is very slow.  You only *need* Invoke() when you need its return value, not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what that write is going to do. For example you can read/write `Tag` property of control in any thread without any problem.

Technically anything that fires a call to `Control.Handle` property should be in `UIThread` because `UIThread` owns that control, so it should be accessed in that thread only, else it will end up throwing an `InvalidOperationException` when debugger attached.